# How to properly map XML content to DTO property in C#

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I have an XML document which looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataProviderConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FileVersion>1</FileVersion>
  <SupportedEventTypes>
    <InvestigateEventType>TimeBasedRefresh</InvestigateEventType>
    <InvestigateEventType>IdBasedRefresh</InvestigateEventType>
    <InvestigateEventType>FileReceived</InvestigateEventType>
  </SupportedEventTypes>
```

And it's parsed down to some DTO:

```cs
[XmlArray(nameof(SupportedEventTypes))]
[XmlArrayItem("InvestigateEventType")]
public virtual string[] SupportedEventTypes { get; set; }
```

Given the document above, `SupportedEventTypes` will have 3 items in it.

Now above fragment contains attributes

```xml
<SupportedEventTypes>
   <InvestigateEventType>TimeBasedRefresh</InvestigateEventType>
   <InvestigateEventType IsDefault="true">IdBasedRefresh</InvestigateEventType>
   <InvestigateEventType IsDefault="true">FileReceived</InvestigateEventType>
</SupportedEventTypes>
```

Let's consider updated DTO

```cs
public class InvestigateEventType
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}

[XmlArray(nameof(SupportedEventTypes))]
[XmlArrayItem("InvestigateEventType")]
public virtual InvestigateEventType[] SupportedEventTypes { get; set; }
```

Given `InvestigateEventType`, `XMLSerializer` should read its content into `Name` property and `IsDefault` attribute into `IsDefault` property.

How to make it happen?

How to make `IsDefault` attribute case-insensitive?

I haven't yet tried this code, because it would take an enormous amount of changes to build it and I'm asking for help upfront.

Comment: You could try this code in a throw-away project or Test project so you don't make enormous changes to the existing code base.

Comment: `SupportedEventTypes ` should probably have the type `InvestigateEventType[]` not `SupportedEventType[]`

Comment: @Crowcoder I'm not asking to debug my code and not looking for a shortcut. I'm asking If anybody solved something similar or has an idea

Comment: Try specifying what exactly the serializer needs to look for when filling in the `Name` and `IsDefault` properties. Perhaps if you specify `[XmlAttribute("IsDefault")]` and `[XmlText]` on the respective properties, it might help

Comment: @thebugsdontwork it worked! Perhaps you can post an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes these (de)serializers need a little nudge in the right direction in order to get the right data into your objects. While JSON is loosely structured, XML files tend to have more stricter structures. Not necessarily by design, but by use.

As you already know judging by your code sample, you can prepend attributes to your objects and object properties which tell the XML serializer what to look for in the XML for that particular property.

Embedded objects can also contain instructions for the XML serializers. So prepending your embedded object's properties with attributes like `[XmlAttribute("IsDefault")]` (telling the XML serializer to look for an XML element's attribute "IsDefault" if it exists) and `[XmlText]` (telling the XML serializer to grab the text inside the XML element) will make life easier for XMLSerializer.

Not only does this make it clear to both you and XMLSerializer what it's looking for, it can also increase the performance of the search, as this prevents XMLSerializer to blindly start querying all possible places where your property could reside.